# Google Maps "Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID"

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift

I am getting following error: "Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID", when I try to integrate Maps in my iOs app.

I think I read all posts about that problem, but I cant find solution. Google maps SDK for iOs is enabled, bundle id is double checked (in log also), APIKey is created several times, and in log GMSServices.provideAPIKey returning true. I also created new app on different google account, with different bundle id and also getting same error.

Any ideas? Is there any problem with google, or I am doing something wrong?

Tnx
Igor

Edit:

Ok, i think I found where the problem is. According to google [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios) it looks like that api key need to have 40 chars, but I am constantly getting api key with length of 39 chars.

Comment: "According to google docs"  There is also 39 characters in docs

Answer (score 6):

**Important**: If you want to practice on google maps from iOS devices then just download the **GoogleMaps.framework** from the below link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios

Unknowingly I have downloaded **GoogleMapsM4B.framework** and faced issues like 'your key may be invalid for your bundle id: com.company.example'

If you want to use **GoogleMapsM4B.framework** in your project then 
 1.You should request support on the Enterprise Support portal(Google's website) 
 2.You must enable **Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work** not **Google Maps SDK for iOS** in Google’s console website.

Incase if you want to use **GoogleMaps.framework** not **GoogleMapsM4B**(Maps for Business) then you need not request support center, you just need to enable Google Maps SDK for iOS in Google's console website.

You can find the key differences between the Google Maps SDK for iOS and the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work(M4B) in the below link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/ios/

and import GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h to your file and pass your api key to below method:
 [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@“Your API Key“];

(or)

If you have valid license then download  GoogleMapsM4B.framework and import GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h to your file and pass api to same method [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@“Your API Key“] 
but I guess you may get this key only after purchasing license.

So the main issue I have faced is... instead of downloading **GoogleMaps.framework** I have downloaded **GoogleMapsM4B.framework** and added to my project. Every time I run my project it gave me an error saying "Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com.example.sampleapp"

Now my project is working properly.

Comment: In 2) step There is no option like Goodle Maps Mobile SDK for Work

Answer (score 2):

GoogleMapsM4B.framework is used for (Maps for Business) 
instead of downloading GoogleMaps.framework and used this framework.

Comment: To solve this, upgrade the version to 1.10.2 or later of GoogleMaps

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem.

Try typing out the API Key if you are copy/pasting. Definitely worth a shot, maybe somehow there are special characters being passed via copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and none of the answers I read really helped me.
The "solution" I finally found was to disable the "Google Maps SDK for iOS" API in the Google Developers Console and to enable it a few seconds later again. Looks like a bug in the enabling functionality at Google's.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me after trying everything else I've found here.

I have deleted the key, then recreated and added the bundle key identifier to the key before creating it.

Although google permits to edit the bundle identifier field for the key later as well, it seems that it doesn't work right when you add the identifier only after creating the key.